# What does 'en' signify in this sentence?

Tags: en

"Mes chers amis, quand je mourrai,
Plantez un saule au cimetière.
J'aime son feuillage éploré ;
La pâleur m'en est douce et chère,
Et son ombre sera légère
À la terre où je dormirai." (A de Musset)

Can it be said what, if anything, the 'en' is referring back to here?

Answer (score 4):

It think *en* refers to *feuillage du saule*. I'd say that the meaning of:

> La pâleur m'**en** est douce et chère

is equivalent to that of:

> **S**a pâleur m'est douce et chère

or

> La pâleur du feuillage du saule m'est douce et chère

Comment: Couldn't it also refer to "son feuillage"? (Not that there's any difference in meaning.)

Comment: @PeterShor thanks, you probably right, as 'feuillage' appears just before the sentence with 'en'. Corrected!